# Predicted values for logistic regression from glm and stat_smooth in ggplot2 are different

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make this logistic regression graph in `ggplot2`.

```
df <- structure(list(y = c(2L, 7L, 776L, 19L, 12L, 26L, 7L, 12L, 8L,
24L, 20L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 23L, 20L, 16L, 12L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 22L,
13L, 7L, 20L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 5L,
5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), n = c(3L, 7L, 789L, 20L, 14L,
27L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 29L, 22L, 17L, 14L, 11L, 30L, 21L, 19L, 14L,
22L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 19L, 10L, 27L, 22L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 23L, 18L,
12L, 19L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x = c(18L,
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L,
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L,
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 59L,
62L, 63L, 66L)), .Names = c("y", "n", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-43L))


mod.fit <- glm(formula = y/n ~ x, data = df, weight=n, family = binomial(link = logit),
        na.action = na.exclude, control = list(epsilon = 0.0001, maxit = 50, trace = T))
summary(mod.fit)

Pi <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)
LD <- (log(Pi /(1-Pi))-mod.fit$coefficients[1])/mod.fit$coefficients[2]
LD.summary <- data.frame(Pi , LD)
LD.summary


plot(df$x, df$y/df$n, xlab = "x", ylab = "Estimated probability")

lin.pred <- predict(mod.fit)
pi.hat <- exp(lin.pred)/(1 + exp(lin.pred))
lines(df$x, pi.hat, lty = 1, col = "red")


segments(x0 = LD.summary$LD, y0 = -0.1, x1 = LD.summary$LD, y1 = LD.summary$Pi,
         lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"))
segments(x0 = 15, y0 = LD.summary$Pi, x1 = LD.summary$LD, y1 = LD.summary$Pi,
         lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"))
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("LD25", "LD50", "LD75"), lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"), bty="n", cex=0.75)
```

[image]

Here is my attempt with `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y/n)) +
            geom_point() +
            stat_smooth(method = "glm", family = "binomial")

p <- p + geom_segment(aes(
                            x = LD.summary$LD
                          , y = 0
                          , xend = LD.summary$LD
                          , yend = LD.summary$Pi
                         )
                         , colour="red"
                       )

p <- p + geom_segment(aes(
                            x = 0
                          , y = LD.summary$Pi
                          , xend = LD.summary$LD
                          , yend = LD.summary$Pi
                         )
                         , colour="red"
                       )

print(p)
```

[image]

### Questions

1. Predicted values for `glm` and `stat_smooth` look different. Are these two methods produces different results or I'm missing something here.
2. My ggplot2 graph is not exactly as base R graph.
3. How to use different colours for line segments in ggplot2?
4. And how to put legend in ggplot2?

Thanks in advance for your help and time. Thanks

Comment: Your base R picture doesn't have the legend in it (commands are fine though) - I'll update it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Thanks for your comment. Please see the legend on the bottomleft.

Comment: yeah, that's because I updated the picture to include the legend.

Comment: Why do you call the variable as "Pi" in the assignment `Pi <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)`? Pi is shortcut of what? Also the same for "LD"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just a couple of minor additions to @mathetmatical.coffee's answer. Typically, `geom_smooth` isn't supposed to replace actual modeling, which is why it can seem inconvenient at times when you want to use specific output you'd get from `glm` and such. But really, all we need to do is add the fitted values to our data frame:

```
df$pred <- pi.hat
LD.summary$group <- c('LD25','LD50','LD75')

ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y/n)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line(aes(y = pred),colour = "black") + 
    geom_segment(data=LD.summary, aes(y = Pi,
                                      xend = LD,
                                      yend = Pi,
                                      col = group),x = -Inf,linetype = "dashed") + 
    geom_segment(data=LD.summary,aes(x = LD,
                                     xend = LD,
                                     yend = Pi,
                                     col = group),y = -Inf,linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

The final little trick is the use of `Inf` and `-Inf` to get the dashed lines to extend all the way to the plot boundaries.

The lesson here is that if all you want to do is add a smooth to a plot, and nothing else in the plot depends on it, use `geom_smooth`. If you want to refer to the output from the fitted model, its generally easier to fit the model outside `ggplot` and then plot.

Comment: Elegant answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does variables "Pi" and "LD" represent (stands for) in the above code?

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER Does it make a difference what the variables are called in order for this specific code example to work? (Typically, "LD50" is a term I've seen used referring to a lethal dose for 50% of a population, but I don't think it's terribly relevant to the question.)

Comment: Definitely not! I thought LD as "Log Difference", and while try to connect the code with theory I fell in trouble. Thx for explanation. Perhaps, some simple comments in the OP asker will prove helpful in terms of theory-code connection.

Answer (score 6):

Modify your `LD.summary` to include a new column with `group` (or appropriate label).

```
LD.summary$group <- c('LD25','LD50','LD75')
```

Then modify your `geom_segment` commands to have a `col=LD.summary$group` in it (and remove the `colour="red"`), which plots each segment in a different colour and adds a legend:

```
geom_segment( aes(...,col=LD.summary$group) )
```

Also, to avoid having to do the `LD.summary$xxx` all the time, feed in `data=LD.summary` to your `geom_segment`:

```
geom_segment(data=LD.summary, aes(x=0, y=Pi,xend=LD, yend=Pi, colour=group) )
```

As to why the graphs are not exactly the same, in the base R graph the x axis goes from ~20 onwards, whereas in `ggplot` it goes from zero onwards. This is because your second `geom_segment` starts at `x=0`.
To fix you could change `x=0` to `x=min(df$x)`.

To get your y axis label use `+ scale_y_continuous('Estimated probability')`.

In summary:

```
LD.summary$group <- c('LD25','LD50','LD75')
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y/n)) +
            geom_point() +
            stat_smooth(method = "glm", family = "binomial") +
            scale_y_continuous('Estimated probability')    # <-- add y label
p <- p + geom_segment(data=LD.summary, aes( # <-- data=Ld.summary
                            x = LD
                          , y = 0
                          , xend = LD
                          , yend = Pi
                          , col = group     # <- colours
                         )
                       )    
p <- p + geom_segment(data=LD.summary, aes( # <-- data=Ld.summary
                            x = min(df$x)   # <-- don't plot all the way to x=0
                          , y = Pi
                          , xend = LD
                          , yend = Pi
                          , col = group     # <- colours
                         )
                       )
print(p)
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: @mathematical.cofee: Thanks for your elegent answer. One observation: why LD25, LD50 are not touching the predicted line as they do in base R graph? Any idea. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 it's something to do with `stat_smooth` which is not generating the same numbers as your `pi.hat` formula: try plotting the first `p` and then doing `lines(x,pi.hat,lty=1,col='red')` to see what I mean. I don't know enough about statistics to help you there unfortunately (i.e. wheter your `pi.hat` calculation is wrong or whether `stat_smooth` is doing some other calculation you are unaware of). All I can suggest is to have a look at the online help for `stat_smooth` and see if it gives any info on how it calculate the smoother. http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_smooth.html

Comment: Although I am sure that it would be trivial to adjust the existing answer, in the current form it does not answer the question. I.e. the graph is not reproduced, since the corners of the segments do not lie on the curve.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Its because `stat_smooth` isn't being passed the same options as you pass in the `glm` call for mod.fit. In particular, the `weight` option isn't passed. Try adding `weight=n` to the `aes` in the `ggplot` call.