# How to plot the S-curve for my logistic regression model?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a S-curve to my logistic regression model, but all I have is this slightly curved line rather than a S shaped one. Is there something I should change in my code?

```
#Log Regression model
logmodel<-glm(y~emp.var.rate,data=Dataset,family=binomial)
summary(logmodel)

#plot
plot(emp.var.rate,y)
x<-seq(from=min(emp.var.rate),to=max(emp.var.rate))
hat.beta<-coef(logmodel)
hat.beta
lines(x, (1 + exp(-hat.beta[1] - hat.beta[2]*x))^(-1), col="blue")

> hat.beta
 (Intercept) emp.var.rate 
  -2.2207829   -0.5203776
```

Comment: I assume your predicted probabilities don't cover the full range between 0 and 1, therefore you will not get the full S curve. What are min and max of predicted values?

Comment: But isn's using this code "x<-seq(from=min(emp.var.rate),to=max(emp.var.rate))" can cover the whole range of x?

Comment: That's going from the min to the max of your observed data. Your observations don't extend far enough for the asymptotes of the s-curve to be apparent. Try `x <- seq(from = min(emp.var.rate) - 3 * diff(range(emp.var.rate)), to = max(emp.var.rate) + 3 * diff(range(emp.var.rate)), length.out = 1000)`. Expand more as needed. (But also realize if you do that, you are extrapolating far beyond the range of your data...)

Comment: Thanks. Now it stretches out further, but still doesn't look S at all...Is this anything to do with my data? Is it because the data is unbalanced?

Comment: there is nothing wrong about that. It's ok if you don't get the S-curve, that's how your data is. Do not extend `x` outside of observed values, that would be extrapolating beyond observed data.

Comment: But if I don't get a S-curve it means I will never get Y=1, is that right? Isn't that a big problem? (Y=1 accounts for only 11% in my data)

Comment: This might be [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8845279/707145).

Comment: You will never get to P(y=1|x) = 1 (not Y = 1), but that's OK. If the model is fit correctly, that's what you data "tells" you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nice function that I used few years ago. It prints the S-shaped predicted~linearized and plot the models mismatches by color and element by weight in the model:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2);

#create your model
m1 <- glm(C(prog25) ~ C(sex) + ageB + gfrB +  mapB + C(M) + C(E) + C(S) + C(T) + C(CRESC) + C(cat0) + tlr4l , data=df10, family=binomial(link=logit))

#extract data for plot
df10$predicted <- predict(m1, type="response")
df10$residuals <- residuals(m1, type = "response")
df10$linearized <- m1$linear.predictors
df10$weights <- m1$weights

#reinterpret as numeric
df10$prog25 <- as.numeric(df10$prog25)

#assign id to know the model "mismatched"
df10$id <- seq(1,nrow(df10))
mism <- df10 %>% filter(prog25 != round(predicted))
for (i in 1:nrow(df10)) {
            if (!is.na(match(df10$id[i],mism$id))) m <- 1
            else m <- 0
            df10$mismatched[i] <- m
            }
#then remove ID
df10$id <- NULL

#define a function to plot the model
gra.tot <- function(dat, varLin, varY, varP, group, fitModel, devModel, dfModel, devNull, dfNull, aicModel, nameX, nameY) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = varLin, y = varY)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=varP, color=as.factor(group)), alpha=.3) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="mismatched", values = c("grey30", "red3")) +
  geom_text(x= min(varLin) + (0.1 * (max(varLin) - min(varLin))) , y=0.5,          hjust=0, label=paste( 'predicted ~ linearized', "\nmismatched: ",sum(group),"/",length(fitModel), '\nres. deviance: ', round(devModel,2) , ' (df: ', round(dfModel,2),')',  '\nnull deviance: ', round(devNull,2), ' (df: ', round(dfNull,2),')', '\nAIC: ', round(aicModel,2) ), col='grey40', size=3, fontface='italic') +
  xlab(as.character(nameX)) +
  ylab(as.character(nameY)) +
  theme_bw()
}

#plot the model
tot <- gra.tot(df10, df10$linearized, df10$predicted, df10$weights, df10$mismatched, m1$fitted, m1$deviance, m1$df.residual, m1$null.deviance, m1$df.null, m1$aic, 'linearized_predictors', 'logit_risk')
```

That should give you an output like this:

[image: LOGISTIC MODEL PLOT]

Hope it helps!