# How to obtain the ggplot graph for the logistic regression imitation in Wikipedia's example in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression

(reproducible example added)

I tried to imitate the Wikipedia's "Probability of passing an exam versus hours of study" logistic regression example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression):

I could not obtain the same ggplot graph in that page, and I couldn't figure out why.

```
df <- data.frame(hour=c(0.50,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,1.75,2.00,2.25,2.50,2.75,3.00,3.25,3.50,4.00,4.25,4.50,4.75,5.00,5.50), pass=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1))

df
#   hour pass
#1   0.50    0
#2   0.75    0
#3   1.00    0
#4   1.25    0
#5   1.50    0
#6   1.75    0
#7   1.75    1
#8   2.00    0
#9   2.25    1
#10  2.50    0
#11  2.75    1
#12  3.00    0
#13  3.25    1
#14  3.50    0
#15  4.00    1
#16  4.25    1
#17  4.50    1
#18  4.75    1
#19  5.00    1
#20  5.50    1

df$pass <- as.factor(df$pass)
my_fit <- glm(df$pass ~ df$hour, data=df, na.action=na.exclude, family="binomial")
summary(my_fit)
```

*NON GGPLOT PLOT WORKS PERFECTLY:*

```
my_table <- summary(my_fit)     
my_table$coefficients[,1] <- invlogit(coef(my_fit))
my_table

anova(my_fit)
library(pscl); pR2(my_fit) # for McFadden rho^2

plot(df$hour, df$pass, xlab="x", ylab="logit values")

LinearPredictions <- predict(my_fit); LinearPredictions
# LinearPredictions is NOT equal to 0.01666 + 0.81827*(1:20)
# LinearPredictions is NOT equal to -4.0777+1.5046*(1:20)
# LinearPredictions are equal to what (I couldn't solve)?

EstimatedProbability.hat <- exp(LinearPredictions)/(1 + exp(LinearPredictions))
EstimatedProbability.hat

EstimatedProbability <- c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75) # Estimated probabilities for which their x levels are wanted to be found

HoursStudied <- (log(EstimatedProbability/(1- EstimatedProbability)) - my_fit$coefficients[1])/ my_fit$coefficients[2]
HoursStudied.summary <- data.frame(EstimatedProbability, HoursStudied)
HoursStudied.summary

plot(df$hour, EstimatedProbability.hat, xlab="studying hours", ylab="estimated probability (pass)") # , xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,1)
# Add red curve
lines(df$hour, EstimatedProbability.hat, lty=1, col="red")
# Vertical dashes
segments(x0=HoursStudied.summary$HoursStudied, y0=0, x1=HoursStudied.summary$HoursStudied, y1=HoursStudied.summary$EstimatedProbability,
         lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"))
# Horizontal dashes
segments(x0=0, y0=HoursStudied.summary$EstimatedProbability, x1=HoursStudied.summary$HoursStudied, 
y1=HoursStudied.summary$EstimatedProbability, lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"))

legend("bottomright", legend=c("HS0.25", "HS0.50", "HS0.75"), lty=2, col=c("darkblue","darkred","darkgreen"), bty="n", cex=0.75)
```

*GGPLOT PLOT FAILS:*
I tried to do the same thing in `ggplot`, but failed:

```
df$EstimatedProbabilities <- EstimatedProbability.hat; df
HoursStudied.summary$group <- c('HS0.25','HS0.50','HS0.75')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=df$pass)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(y=EstimatedProbabilities), colour="black") + 
geom_segment(data=HoursStudied.summary, aes(y=EstimatedProbability,
xend=HoursStudied, yend=EstimatedProbability, col=group), x=-Inf, linetype="dashed") + 
geom_segment(data=HoursStudied.summary, aes(x=HoursStudied,
xend=HoursStudied, yend=EstimatedProbability, col=group), y=-Inf, linetype="dashed")
```

Problem: The `ggplot` curve is the same with that of `plot`, however, it draws the whole function below y=0 line. Why?

Comment: Probably because of `ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=df$pass))`. You're plotting 0 or 1 on the y-axis as a scatterplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:** you need your `df$pass` to be numeric, not a factor. I would also not map any aesthetics in the initial `ggplot` call, and just pass them in the `geom_point` and `geom_line` calls.

```
df$pass <- as.numeric(df$pass) - 1

ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x=hour,y=pass)) +
    geom_line(aes(x=hour,y=EstimatedProbabilities)) +
    geom_segment(data=HoursStudied.summary, aes(y=EstimatedProbability, xend=HoursStudied, yend=EstimatedProbability, col=group), x=-Inf, linetype="dashed") + 
    geom_segment(data=HoursStudied.summary, aes(x=HoursStudied, xend=HoursStudied, yend=EstimatedProbability, col=group), y=-Inf, linetype="dashed")
```

[image: pic]

Comment: This fixed the plot range problem for y. Now, y values are between 0 and 1. However, in the `ggplot` graph in Wikipedia's page, all the points are located at y=0 or y=1, but with the change you offered, the data points are still on the curve instead of being at y=0 or y=1 location.

Comment: Ah okay, the ggplot matches your base R plot that you said works perfectly so I assumed that was what you were after.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I just wanna learn that: 1) Is my base R plot wrong and flawed (i.e. must it also have points located only at y=0 and y=1 line)? 2) In your edited solution, unfortunately, vertical dashes were removed. In your 1st solution they were there. Is there a way to recover these vertical lines in your 2nd solution? 3) Why do you subtract 1 from pass in your 2nd solution?

Comment: You're welcome. 1) Your base R plot doesn't actually plot `pass`, does it? It's just plotting `hour` vs `estimated probability`. 2) Oops, just missed out the second `geom_segment` call. Edited now. 3) We need to subtract 1 from the `as.numeric` `pass` data because when you convert from factor to numeric, factor level 0 becomes numeric 1; factor 1 becomes numeric 2. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

The question is complicating what can be made simple with `geom_smooth`. Note that the predictions are of `type = "response"`, following [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103645/why-does-a-binomial-glm-give-negative-predictions#103647) to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

```
my_fit <- glm(pass ~ hour, data = df, na.action = na.exclude,
              family = "binomial")
pred <- predict(my_fit, type = "response")
pred_df <- data.frame(hour = df$hour, pred)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = hour, y = pass)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"),
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = pred_df, aes(x = hour, y = pred), colour = "blue") +
  geom_hline(data = data.frame(c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)),
             aes(yintercept = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)),
             colour = "darkgrey", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: SOF did not allow me to select both answers as solution. Also, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845279/predicted-values-for-logistic-regression-from-glm-and-stat-smooth-in-ggplot2-are , joran said "if all you want to do is add a smooth to a plot, and nothing else in the plot depends on it, use `geom_smooth`. If you want to refer to the output from the fitted model, its generally easier to fit the model OUTSIDE `ggplot` and then plot.". And therefore, I defined `df$EstimatedProbabilities` and `HoursStudied.summary$group` before `ggplot` just as he did. I don't know whether it is a must .

Comment: 1) In your solution, hour=3 studied student normally must pass with prob~0.62. The solution specified that student as prob=0. So, the black dots in the image corresponds to the actual data, not the predicted data. Is there a way to show both actual/predicted data on the same `ggplot` graph (with different colors)? 2) Your solution missing vertical and horizontal dashes at prob=c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75). Is there a way to add them to your solution?